# Looking for a better design pattern for methods of enums in Rust

Tags: rust, methods, enums

I need a way to put different objects that all implement a certain trait `integrate()` in one enum. This enum shall implement a method that calls its variant's method `integrate()` in a certain way e.g. many times.
I tried to make a very simple example, but it is still not as short as I would want it to be.
Some more explanation: I want to write a solver that integrates certain differential equations i.e. calculate how a physical system behaves over a certain time span. For each time step the method `integrate()` is called. But when I execute the program I want to be able to choose *which* physical system is used at runtime. My idea was to have an enum that has the different physical systems in it e.g. `OscillatorA` and `OscillatorB` (in reality this could be a double pendulum, or a vibrating string - doesn't matter).

```rust
pub trait Integrate {
    fn integrate(&mut self);
}

pub struct OscillatorA {
    z: u32,
}

impl Integrate for OscillatorA {
    fn integrate(&mut self) {
        self.z += 1; // something happens here
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct OscillatorB {
    x: u32,
    y: u32,
}

impl Integrate for OscillatorB {
    fn integrate(&mut self) {
        self.x += 1; // something different happens here
        self.y += 2;
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Oscillator {
    A(OscillatorA),
    B(OscillatorB),
    // ... many other physical systems come here
}

impl Oscillator {
    pub fn new(num: &u64) -> Self {
        match num {
            0 => Self::A(OscillatorA { z: 1 }),
            1.. => Self::B(OscillatorB { x: 1, y: 2 }),
        }
    }
}

impl Integrate for Oscillator {
    fn integrate(&mut self) {
        // this looks like it should be redundant:
        match self {
            Self::A(osc) => osc.integrate(),
            Self::B(osc) => osc.integrate(),
        }
    }
}

pub fn integrate_n_times(object: &mut impl Integrate, n: u64) {
    for _ in 0..n {
        object.integrate();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let which = 0; // can be set via commandline arguments.

    let mut s = Oscillator::new(&which);
    integrate_n_times(&mut s, 10);
    // ..
}
```

The function `integrate_n_times(&mut self, n)` will call n times the `integrate()` method required by the `Integrate`-trait. But it somehow doesn't feel right, because it will at each iteration solve a match-statement. I guess with compiler optimizations this might be avoided, but it somehow "feels" wrong, because it certainly reads like this.
Is there a better design pattern I am missing? Should I require the method "integrate_n_times" through the trait as well? (But then I would rely on it being written correctly in every Oscillator struct).

I somehow need to have one "main-struct" that I contains all the different physical systems and can call them depending on what arguments I pass to the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use dynamic dispatch here. While it's generally slower than using static dispatch, I would imagine it's faster than a massive match cases. Plus I think it's easier to work with, as long as we don't try to get the original type with Any and down-casting.

```
impl Oscillator {
    pub fn new(num: &u64) -> Box<dyn Integrate> {
        match num {
            0 => Box::new(OscillatorA { z: 1 }),
            1.. => Box::new(OscillatorB { x: 1, y: 2 }),
        }
    }
}

pub fn integrate_n_times(object: &mut Box<dyn Integrate>, n: u64) {
    for _ in 0..n {
        object.integrate();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let which = 0; // can be set via commandline arguments.
    let mut my_oscillator: Box<dyn Integrate> = Oscillator::new(&which);  
    integrate_n_times(&mut my_oscillator, 10);
}
```

Comment: could I somehow know that each separate function call -  i.e. doing an integration of oscillator A or oscillator B etc - is compiler-optimized on its own? Every single integration operation would be "dispatched" independent of others. I would just need a way to put them all in one container (that's why i chose the enum). 
Thank you, I will read up on `dyn` and `Box`!

Comment: Fyi `Box dyn Integrate` is a pointer to an object on the heap which is guaranteed to implement the `Integrate` trait. You could make a collection with: `Vec<Box<dyn Integrate>>`. Now in order to know which function you're calling you have 2 options, the `Any` trait or have a `fn which() -> Oscillator` on `Integrate` trait. Then each implementation will return the correct enum variant, and then you'll yet again have to use match to figure out what type that was.

Comment: I looked a while at your code, but I am still unsure what the difference is. 
The match statement is still evaluated with each iteration.

Comment: @exocortex Ah you're right! The `new` function needs to return a specific type that implements the Integrate trait instead of the enum. Since they all implement it, it was still working fine but running the match. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Ahh, now I get it! Thank you! 
I just realized; do I still need the enum `Oscillator` this way? I guess I could just have the function `new() -> Box< ... >` without the enum.

Comment: @exocortex exactly!

Comment: Will a large match statements be slower than a VtableLookup?